# Is there a way to limit or whitelist which files the command "raco test" should execute, based on file names or file extensions?

Tags: unit-testing, racket, raco, rackunit

I'm writing unit tests using `rackunit` and running them using `raco` through the command `raco test .`, which recursively finds all racket files and executes them, including files that do not contain unit tests at all. It just runs everything.

According to what I investigated, the idiomatic way to write unit tests in racket is to write a test module inside the implementation file, and not have a separate file for them. The problem is that I have multiple different implementations of the same specification that share the same unit tests, so I need to import all the implementations in a separate file and run the unit tests there.

So I end up with just a few unit test files, and a lot of racket files that do not contain unit tests, but `raco test` ends up scanning everything anyway.

I'm looking for a way to use `raco test` to only run files that have a specific pattern in the name. Like `*.test.rkt`, `*.spec.rkt`, `test-*.rkt`, or similar (like in `jest` for js or `pytest` for python).

Is this possible?

I looked into `test-include-paths` in `info.rkt` files, but it seems to be for files that are not racket files, and not for whitelisting which files to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh93` as your shell, you can use a recursive glob to find all the matching files:

```bash
raco test **/*.test.rkt
```

(`bash` might need a `shopt -s globstar` first)

or any Unix-y system:

```bash
find . -name "*.test.rkt" -exec raco test \{\} +
```